# Batch: For /F Loop Does Not Extract All Tokens

Tags: sqlite, batch-file, for-loop

I have a sqlite3 database called "Cookies" that has two tables:

```
cookies meta
```

When I execute:

```
sqlite3 Cookies .tables
```

I receive:

```
cookies  meta
```

Therefore when I execute my batch file "dumbdb.bat" passing it the database name "Cookies":

```
@echo OFF
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=   " %%F IN ('sqlite3 %1 .tables') DO (
    ECHO %%F
)
```

I expect it to give me the output:

```
cookies
meta
```

But instead I get:

```
cookies
```

Can anyone see what I'm messing up here? I've played a bunch with various entries for Tokens and Delims, but none of them give me the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%F In ('sqlite3 %1 .tables') Do Echo %%F %%G
```

Or:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('sqlite3 %1 .tables') Do Echo %%F
```

Or if you want each outputting separately:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('sqlite3 %1 .tables'
) Do For %%A In (%%F) Do Echo %%A
```

**Edit**

The following performs a count too!

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('sqlite3 %1 .tables'
) Do For %%A In (%%F) Do Set/A i+=1&Echo %%A
If %i% Gtr 0 Echo There were %i% tables in total
Pause
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize the letters went up for each token. Is there any way for me to know how many tokens there are so I can cycle through all of them? 

In this case I know the number of tables, but most places I use this I will not.